# CSS3 Mobile Scale and transform3d

Tags: ios, css, mobile, scale

I try to make an effect on my background-image like a zoom for create a fake depth, it's perfect work on my desktop but nothing on my mobile, i have already try to add -webkit- but nothing.

This is my code and the two first line doesn't work :

```
  .background {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale(1.20);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale(1.20);
    background: url(../css/img/ny2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

I have other effects on my page and they work but only this effect doesn't work   (transform).

Comment: can you please comment the mobile os/version

Comment: sorry my os version is 7.1.2

Comment: how u making the zoom function?

Comment: transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale(1.20);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale(1.20);                                    This doesn't work on mobile

Comment: up please ! i doesn't find any solution